# Should I use <div id="page" class="site"> in a custom Wordpress theme?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm inspecting some of the Wordpress official themes (i.e. TwentyNineteen and Underscores), and noticed that there is a particular `div` right after the `body`:

`<div id="page" class="site">`

When developing a custom theme from scratch, should I use this ID and class too? In other words, are these required and used by Wordpress, or are arbitrarily added by these particular themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's up to you as a theme developer to apply these and use them in your CSS styles (for combined selectors), but that's not a "Wordpress rule" or anything like that.